# Is there a way to do a negative match using regex sub?

Tags: r, regex

Say I have a vector of strings,

```
g<-c("bunchofstuff>query=true/fun/weird>bunchofstuff", "bunchofstuff>query=animals/octopus/weird>bunchofstuff", "bunchofstuff>query=flowers/sunshine/fun>bunchofstuff", "
bunchofstuff>query=fun/true/sunshine>bunchofstuff"
```

and I want to essentially use sub to erase anything after query=, until the end of the string, IF query= is not followed by true (ideally in any position). As far as I can tell, there isn't a useful substitution for ! in sub (seems to be some workarounds in grepl).
What I want is

```
newvariable<-c("bunchofstuff>query=true/fun/weird>bunchofstuff", "bunchofstuff>query=", "bunchofstuff>query=", "bunchofstuff>query=fun/true/sunshine>bunchofstuff"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
sub('query=\\K(?:(?!true).)+$', '', g, perl=TRUE)
```

This technique uses a negative lookahead assertion `(?!true)` that checks before each character `.` if "true" doesn't follow. All is in a non-capturing group repeated until the end of the string `$`.

`\\K` is used to start the matched string after it to preserve the `query=` substring. (Note that it's only a convenient way to avoid a capture group or to rewrite `query=` in the replacement string.)

You can be more specific using word-boundaries to be sure that "true" isn't a part of another word:

```
sub('query=\\K(?:(?!\\btrue\\b).)+$', '', g, perl=TRUE)
```